# How to relocate a div?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a PHP (or non-javascript) way of relocating a div in a Wordpress post.

What I'm trying to achieve is this...

In my post text editor the very first thing I have is:

```
<div class="this-div"><p>Hi there!</p></div>
```

and then I have the rest of my post text, which of course, when looked at in a browser, looks like this...

**THIS IS A POST TITLE**

Hi there!

This is the rest of the post text.

I'd like to 'relocate' the div so when you look at the post in a browser you see 'Hi there!' up above the post title, like this...

Hi there!

**THIS IS A POST TITLE**

This is the rest of the post text.

I did find some JS code that will do this, however there is some lag when the div moves (you can actually see the div and the post title switch places) and also, I'd like something that will work for people who have JS turned off in their browsers.

I don't know PHP but I do know how to cut and paste! Lol!

I don't know what info you need, but I'm using WP 4.4.2 and I'm using the Genesis framework with the FocusPro child theme. And for my fellow Genesis users out there, I do have Genesis Simple Hooks.

Thanx to all in advance,

Paul :)

Comment: I think you can use css to show "Hi there" before the post title. This can be made by absolute position of css.

Comment: I think, the code is in page.php or single.php file in theme folder. search the `class="this-div"` text in the files and changed it

Comment: if you want Jquery solution I can suggest you.

Comment: Hi Ahossain and Tamil, thank-you very much for your suggestions. Ahossain, using CSS was actually the very first thing I tried, and it did relocate the div, but on a responsive theme this will throw everything below the div out of whack when you make the screen smaller. Tamil, unfortunately, your suggestion won't work with what I need, as I have the div on every post, but the content in each div is different and page specific.

Comment: Hi Rahul. I'm actually using a Jquery solution at the moment, but it creates lag; when you go to the post in a browser you can actually see the div and the post title switch places as the page loads, also, I'd like something that will work for people who have JS turned off in their browsers.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Created a custom field with a shortcode.

Thanks to all for your help.

Paul :)